# following function gives an error while converting to swift 3, how can I convert it

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm using branch io and attempting to implement following method in swift 3.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)

    return true
}
```

but it gives an error near the `@` sign in `@escaping`,how can I covert this to swift 3.
hope your help

Comment: Compiles fine. Please post error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Swift 3.0 :

`func application(_ application: UIApplication,willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool {
        return Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)
}`